# pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (click 7.1.2 (/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('click>=8.0.3'))

Tags: python, docker, flask, airflow

`ERROR: flask 1.1.4 has requirement click<8.0,>=5.1, but you'll have click 8.1.3 which is incompatible.`

When i am trying yo run my package getting error:

````
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 581, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 909, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 800, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (click 7.1.2 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('click>=8.0.3'), {'fuji'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:```
````

Comment: So have you tried installing a version of click between versions 5.1 and 8.0?

Comment: yes i tried but no luck

Comment: I would try making a clean virtual environment and installing flask there, so it will automatically install the correct dependencies.